# Unexpected character. (near "?")

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do the following query in phpMyAdmin and errors occur.I have looked at similar problems, but I still can't figure out why it doesn't work.

```
INSERT INTO discussion_forum (event_type, title) VALUES ('edx.forum.thread.viewed', 'Which of the stories you've seen or read can you relate to? Why?')
```

The static analysis is

```
3 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected character. (near "?" at position 143)
Unexpected character. (near "?" at position 148)
Ending quote ' was expected. (near "" at position 151)
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Use double quotes (") since in your string it has  single quote which will lead to throw  error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape `'` by doubling them,

```
'Which of the stories you''ve seen or read can you relate to? Why?'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a quote (') in your string, you should escape it with backslash (\)

```
INSERT INTO discussion_forum (event_type, title) VALUES 
('edx.forum.thread.viewed', 'Which of the stories you\'ve seen or read can you relate to? Why?')
```

Comment: `\'` may work in some SQL engines, but the standard says a single quote is escaped by an additional single quote, as in Srinivasan Sekar's solution. Specifically, `\'` will work on MySQL only if `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` mode is not active.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is ' this quot so you need to change this like below

```
INSERT INTO discussion_forum (event_type, title) VALUES ('edx.forum.thread.viewed', 'Which of the stories you\'ve seen or read can you relate to? Why?')
```